# Failed to catch variable pass from view to controller? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to pass a variable from view to the controller. However, the controller param doesn't include the parameter even though I included. Can someone have a check for me?
Thanks

show.html.erb

```
    <div class="col-xs-8">
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
        <%= image_tag @post.avatar_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        <br>
      <strong>Tag:</strong>

      <%= @post.tag %>

    </p>
    <%= button_to "Add New Version", versions_path(:pid => "123"), :class => "btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

</div>
```

I tried to click Add new Version in this webpage... and it will go to versions#index

so this is my version index.

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  layout "loginpage"
  #before_action :set_version, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @heading = "Add new version"
    @effect = Effect.new
    p "hello world"
    p params
    p params[:pid]
    p @effect
    p "hello owlrd"
```

I tried to print out the params and see if there exist a pid param, heres the output

```
Started GET "/versions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-18 19:17:28 +1100
Processing by VersionsController#index as HTML
"hello world"
{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"versions"}
nil
#<Effect id: nil, effect1: nil, effect2: nil, effect3: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
"hello owlrd"
```

It seems like I can't put pid into params.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :trashes

  resources :versions

  resources :effects

  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  resources :homes

  # routing to the login page
  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

rake routes

```
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                 trashes GET    /trashes(.:format)             trashes#index
                         POST   /trashes(.:format)             trashes#create
               new_trash GET    /trashes/new(.:format)         trashes#new
              edit_trash GET    /trashes/:id/edit(.:format)    trashes#edit
                   trash GET    /trashes/:id(.:format)         trashes#show
                         PATCH  /trashes/:id(.:format)         trashes#update
                         PUT    /trashes/:id(.:format)         trashes#update
                         DELETE /trashes/:id(.:format)         trashes#destroy
                versions GET    /versions(.:format)            versions#index
                         POST   /versions(.:format)            versions#create
             new_version GET    /versions/new(.:format)        versions#new
            edit_version GET    /versions/:id/edit(.:format)   versions#edit
                 version GET    /versions/:id(.:format)        versions#show
                         PATCH  /versions/:id(.:format)        versions#update
                         PUT    /versions/:id(.:format)        versions#update
                         DELETE /versions/:id(.:format)        versions#destroy
                 effects GET    /effects(.:format)             effects#index
                         POST   /effects(.:format)             effects#create
              new_effect GET    /effects/new(.:format)         effects#new
             edit_effect GET    /effects/:id/edit(.:format)    effects#edit
                  effect GET    /effects/:id(.:format)         effects#show
                         PATCH  /effects/:id(.:format)         effects#update
                         PUT    /effects/:id(.:format)         effects#update
                         DELETE /effects/:id(.:format)         effects#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                   homes GET    /homes(.:format)               homes#index
                         POST   /homes(.:format)               homes#create
                new_home GET    /homes/new(.:format)           homes#new
               edit_home GET    /homes/:id/edit(.:format)      homes#edit
                    home GET    /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#show
                         PATCH  /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#update
                         PUT    /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#update
                         DELETE /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#destroy
                    root GET    /                              devise/sessions#new
```

Comment: I think this is a routing issue did you setup the route for index method to receive pid as dynamic segment. but you will be face another issue if you modify the route for index method so `:pid` is passed as dynamic segment, there will be a conflict with the route for the show method because both routes will have the same signature i.e `controller_name/dynamic_segment` + plus both will be using the same `http verb`

Comment: Lemme update it and paste my routes.rb. I checked many posts, they said this will work.

Comment: can you show the url gets generated from `versions_path(:pid => "123")` you can grab this after loading the view on the browser.

Comment: It is like this `http://localhost:3000/versions? `

Comment: I know it should be ?pid=123 on the browser..

Comment: you might want to try write the path directly without using the `path helper method`, i.e `<%= button_to "Add New Version", '/versions?pid=123', :class => "btn btn-default", :method => :get %>` instead of `<%= button_to "Add New Version", versions_path(:pid => "123"), :class => "btn btn-default", :method => :get %>`

Comment: It still doesn't work.. But that inspired me, maybe I force the method to get thats why the route file do something. So after I removed the `method get` from the line. IT is working now!

Comment: But now it is calling version#create.. which is not what I want..

Comment: it is because button by default submit post request. you should convert `button_to` to `link_to` so it will product `<a>` tag instead of `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not with your routes but with the helper you are using.If you look at the html generated by [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), it would be something like this:

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "new" %>
# => "<form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
#      <div><input value="New" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

so it makes a form for it and forms ***by default send a post request***

**FIX:**

***Change button_to helper to link_to***, it by default sends a get request so you won't have to specify method option for it

```
<%= link_to "Add New Version", versions_path(:pid => "123"), :class => "btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
```